# How to configure spring-oauth2 to use jackson 2.x

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-4

Currently Spring OAuth 2 (version 2.0.7) uses Jackson-mapper-asl 1.9.13.

Can I configure the spring-oauth2 to use Jackson 2.x ? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Spring Security OAuth2 allows you to use either of them. Just make sure that you use Jackson 2 classes in your code (ObjectMapper should be of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper and not org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper). Same with Annotations.

If you are still having problems, please share some sample code.

Comment: Sorry my fault, the problem was in other component (my code).